# Passing Serializable from one Activity to another does not work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

I want to pass an Object from one Activity to another. Sending just strings and arrays would be a pain in the ass since my object contains a vector with some other objects. I am trying and reading for hours now but I just can't make it work.

```
// Room.java the object I want to send
public class Room implements Serializable {
  private int heating;
  private boolean light;
  private String id;
  private String name;

  // A list of additional devices, may be empty
  private Vector<Device> devices = new Vector();

  ...
}

// HomeScreen.java - here I call my intent to switch to RoomScreen
public void onOpenRoom(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RoomScreen.class);
    Room testRoom = new Room("1", "test", 1, true);

    mBundle.putSerializable("roomObject", testRoom);
    myIntent.putExtras(mBundle);

    startActivity(myIntent);
}

// RoomScreen.java This is the activity where I want to use the passed object
public class RoomScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Room room;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);

    room = (Room) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("roomObject");

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(room.getName());
    createElements();
}
```

However I always get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String automaton.automaton.Room.getName()' on a null object reference
```

I also tried getting the object with

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);

    Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("roomObject");
    room = (Room) myBundle.getSerializable("roomObject");

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(room.getName());
    createElements();
}
```

Then I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

What am I doing wrong?

Complete code for Room.java

```
public class Room implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
private int heating;
private boolean light;
private String id;
private String name;

// A list of additional devices, may be empty
private Vector<Device> devices = new Vector();

public Room() {

}

/**
 * Sets initial heating and light
 *
 * @param heating
 * @param light
 */
public Room(String id, String name, int heating, boolean light) {
    this.id = id;
    this.heating = heating;
    this.light = light;
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean getLight() {
    return this.light;
}

public int getHeating() {
    return this.heating;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

/**
 * Adds a new device to the room.
 *
 * @param device
 */
public void addDevice(Device device) {
    this.devices.add(device);
}

/**
 * Searches and returns a device by its id
 *
 * @param id
 * @return Device
 * @throws NoSuchElementException
 */
public Device getDeviceById(String id) throws NoSuchElementException {
    boolean found = false;
    int foundAt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        if(devices.elementAt(i).getId() == id) {
            found = true;
            foundAt = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found) return devices.elementAt(foundAt);
    else throw new NoSuchElementException("Device not found!");
}

/**
 * Returns all devices attached to the room
 */
public Vector<Device> getDevices() {
    return this.devices;
}

/**
 * Returns the id of the room.
 *
 * @return
 */
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
}
```

Comment: well first of all link the ENTIRE code for the object that implements serializable this is where we will find your mistake

Comment: Yes, we do not see where the object is instantiated.

Comment: You might also want to consider using Parcelable instead of Serializable.

Comment: Might be easier to use a parcelable as these are more optimized for data transfer among activity -> activity

Comment: I added the complete code for Room.java. Trying to solve it with parcelable now!

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend you to consider using the more optimized Parcelable interface.

But, it was not the problem which caused you the NPE. The way you tried to attach and retrieve your Room object was incorrect.

## UPDATE:

Attach your serializable object like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RoomScreen.class);
Room testRoom = new Room("1", "test", 1, true);
myIntent.putExtra("roomObject", testRoom);
```

And, get your object like this:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    room = (Room) bundle.getSerializable("roomObject");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as it turns out extras is always null. I'll try it with parcelable tomorrow ..

Comment: Sorry, I have missed another problem in your code (Did you forget to initialize the mBundle object?). You can try the updated answer. In this way you don't need to explicitly initialize the bundle yourself.

Comment: Do you mean getIntent().getExtras(); instead of just intent? It still doesn't work, extras ist null.